# How to convert an array of objects to query string javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, query-string

I have the following array of objects below, the output of the url with query string would be:

`http://example.com/api/accounts?services=10&channels=20`

I tried to do as below, but `encodeURIComponent` get the url of the current page, but I would like the url output to be as above

Today the output base URL is `http://example.com/`, But I would like the base URL to be `http://example.com/api/accounts`

**Array from object**

```
[
  {
    "id": "10",
    "name": "PIX",
    "key": "services"
  }, 
  {
    "id": "20",
    "name": "Chat",
    "key": "channels"
  }
]
```

**Function convert**

```
function sendFiltersToApi() {
      const params = filters.map((param: any) => {
        return (
          encodeURIComponent(param.key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(param.id)
        )
      })
      const queryString = params.join('&')
      return `${queryString}`
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like the encoding - try creating your own. Does this work for you?

```
type IFilter = {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    key: string
}

const sendFiltersToAPI = (): string => {
  const params: string = filters.reduce((acc: string, param: IFilter) => `${acc}&${param.key}=${param.id}`, '');

  return `http://example.com/api/accounts?${params.substring(1)}`;
}
```